# Python - Read messages from Service bus topic and then store them in a container with the same name

Tags: python, storage, subscription, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am new to this, but the code seems to be not working.
Intension is to read json message from Service bus endpoint and then copy and store them in a  blob container, but to keep the integrity constant throughout need to keep the name as is.

Do not have much knowledge on this , collected these codes from some blog.
Also if i can listen without func that will also help

Here is the code piece:

```
with receiver:
    for msg in receiver:
        print(str(msg))
        logging.info('Python ServiceBus trigger processed an Topics: %s', msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
        #receiver.complete_message(msg)
        
        temp_path = tempfile.gettempdir()
        
        # Create a file in the local data directory to upload and download
        local_file_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".txt"
        upload_file_path = os.path.join(temp_path, local_file_name)
        
        # Write text to the file
        file = open(upload_file_path, 'w')
        file.write(msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
        file.close()
        
        # Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=local_file_name)
        
        print("\nUploading to Azure Storage as blob:\n\t" + local_file_name)
        
        
        # Upload the created file
        with open(upload_file_path, "rb") as data:
            blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

Comment: Your code mostly looks fine. Only thing I would suggest is that you don't really need to save the message contents in a local file and upload that file. You should be able to set the blob contents based on the decoded message body.

Answer (score 1):

Here we need to create a function where we can configure messages to read which are received from Service Bus queues.

For this we need to mention the bindings in function.json file as below:

**serviceBusTrigger**:

```
{
"bindings": [
    {
    "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
    "name": "inputMessage",
    "connection": "AzureServiceBusConnectionString",
    "queueName": "inputqueue",
    "accessRights": "listen",
    "direction": "in"
    },
    {
    "type": "blob",
    "name": "inputBlob",
    "path": "container/{inputMessage}",
    "connection": "EnterConnection",
    "direction": "in"
    }
],
"disabled": false
}
```

**queueTrigger:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "inputBlob",
      "path": "incontainer/{queueTrigger}",
      "connection": "testweblog_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "name": "myQueue",
      "queueName": "myqueue",
      "connection": " EnterConnection _STORAGE",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

For more information about the triggers please refer to [input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python#example) and [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=python#example) triggers:

A queue is basically for first-in-first-out messages. When a message comes from the service bus, the service bus queue trigger gets fired and the Azure Function is called. In the Azure Function, we can process the message and then deliver it to destination.

Below is the sample code to receive service bus queue.

```
Import os
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient


CONNECTION_STR = os.environ['SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STR']
QUEUE_NAME = os.environ["SERVICE_BUS_QUEUE_NAME"]


servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR)


with servicebus_client:
    receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
    with receiver:
        received_msgs = receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=10, max_wait_time=5)
        for msg in received_msgs:
            print(str(msg))
            receiver.complete_message(msg)


print("Receive is done.")
```

For more information refer to [Azure Service Bus client library for Python](https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/)

Comment: Thank you, i had to use blobservice to store these messages in a container

Answer (score 0):

servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=True)
msg_topic="XYZ"
with servicebus_client:
receiver = servicebus_client.get_subscription_receiver(topic_name=TOPIC_NAME, subscription_name=SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, max_wait_time=5)
with receiver:
for msg in receiver:
print(str(msg))
msg_topic=msg
print(str(msg_topic))
receiver.complete_message(msg)
block_blob_service=BlockBlobService(account_name='stgidpdev',account_key='ZZZZ')
block_blob_service.create_container('servicebuscontainer',public_access=PublicAccess.Container)
print('Container Created')
#from azure.storage.blob import ContentSetting
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_text('servicebuscontainer','myblockblob',str(msg_topic),content_settings=None)